# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type User

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
databaseQuestion = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(KrgDOh_GnwpIons_r9Q);
        databaseQuestion.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//                System.out.println("VAL"+dataSnapshot.getValue());
                //clearing the previous artist list
                usersQuestions.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //iterating through all the nodes

                    //getting artist
                   System.out.println("VAL"+postSnapshot.getValue());
                    User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    //adding artist to the list
                   usersQuestions.add(user);
                }




                //creating adapter
                QuestionUserList userQuestionsAdapter = new QuestionUserList(getActivity(), usersQuestions);
                //attaching adapter to the listview
               questionsList.setAdapter(userQuestionsAdapter);
        }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I am facing the following error
  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type

I want to fetch the data and display it in Listview. Please help out.

Comment: Please add you database structure.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/qT8iX

Comment: @HarishR: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please instead edit your question to include the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen   https://paste.ofcode.org/JGfBra3ydkLmXJsycPsk9a

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `users` node is the direct child of Firebase root, to get those values, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            String question = ds.child("question").getValue(String.class);
            String userId = ds.child("userId").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", address + " / " + question + " / " + userId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Having those values, you can create a new object of your class as add it to `questionsList` list. Also don't forget to declare that list inside the `onDataChange()` method, otherwise it will be null.

Hope it hels.

Comment: Hey but i am searching based on ID. Youve not looked into it

Comment: Yes i did. Look closely. getChildren() return those ids and child("userId") returns a particular id. What is the error?

Comment: i was speaking about this id     databaseQuestion = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(KrgDOh_GnwpIons_r9Q);

Comment: Then you just need too change `.child("userId")` with `.child("K‌​rgDOh_GnwpIons_r9Q")`. Does it work?